# Strange Bootstrap carousel issue with other elements' rounded corners

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css

On a page I have a Bootstrap 3 carousel set to slide after 10 seconds, and the carets for manual switching.

In an entirely different section I have a div:

```
border-radius:6px;
-webkit-border-radius:6px;
overflow:hidden;
```

Whenever the carousel slides, either manually or on its own, the rounded corners on all other elements on the page stop working for the duration of the carousel animation.

The CSS above remains in place, it isn't toggled or disabled or anything. It's just as if it wasn't there.

Happens on both Chrome and Safari.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: What css selectors are you using? More code please.

Comment: it's a div.tweets inside a div.col-md-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same issue can be solved by using `z-index` on the *carousel*

```
border-radius:6px;
-webkit-border-radius:6px;
overflow:hidden;
z-index:1000;
```